# How to solve CORS error in api (implemented using Lumen) while testing using Swagger UI

Tags: php, laravel, cors, swagger, lumen

I am facing a CORS error while firing an API created using Lumen via Swagger UI eated. So I created a middleware to solve this CORS problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
 {
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
      * @return mixed
    */
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
           'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
           'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type,  Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

       if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
       {
           return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
       }

       $response = $next($request);
       foreach($headers as $key => $value)
       {
           $response->header($key, $value);
       }

       return $response;
    }
}
```

And used this middleware in my route for that API, now after using this my corse error problem solved but API is not working properly, throwing an error for the below code:

```
//**** code that throwing error starts ****

       $config = app()->make('config');

           $data = array_merge([
            'client_id'     => $config->get('secrets.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => $config->get('secrets.client_secret'),
            'grant_type'    => $grantType,
            'username' =>$data['username'],
            'password' =>$data['password']
        ], $data);

            $http = new Client();

            $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'];
            $guzzleResponse = $http->post( $config->get('app.url').'/oauth/token', [

            'form_params' => $data,
        ]);
             $tokenDetails = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody(),true);

//************** Code throwing error ends ******
```

Now when I remove the middleware from route the API is working fine with POSTMAN but throwing CORS error for SWagger, and when I use the middleware for solving CORS problem, API is not working properly.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: some time CORS error if middleware not used , 500 internal server error if used.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in .htaccess

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
after RewriteEngine On line